# Python BS4 find_all replaces text inside the tag with <!--empty-->

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape mortgage rates from https://www.td.com/ca/en/personal-banking/products/mortgages/mortgage-rates/

When I use find_all to get value from a cell in specific table, the returned value is "**!--empty--**" instead of the text within that cell.

The actual html for that cell is:

```
<span class="h2 ng-binding ng-isolate-scope" code="a.reslrates.MTGF036C" high-ratio="false" resl-rate="" type="S">2.54%</span>
```

The result which is returned is:

```
<span class="h2" code="a.reslrates.MTGF036C" high-ratio="false" resl-rate="" type="S"><!--empty--></span>
```

Instead of the 2.54% rate text, I get !--empty-- result. I get Am I missing something here? Full code below:

```
html_text = requests.get("https://www.td.com/ca/en/personal-banking/products/mortgages/mortgage-rates/").text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")

# Get the table
table = soup.find("div", class_="td-rates-table rates-bg-row1").table

rows = table.tbody.find_all("tr")

for row in rows:
  for rate in row.find_all("td"):
      print(rate)
```

I appreciate all responses! Thanks a lot!

Comment: the web site is using javascript that loaded dynamically. please use selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using selenium. Please install necessay dependencies and execute the script.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

url = 'https://www.td.com/ca/en/personal-banking/products/mortgages/mortgage-rates/'
# html_text = requests.get("https://www.td.com/ca/en/personal-banking/products/mortgages/mortgage-rates/").text
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

# Get the table
table = soup.find("div", class_="td-rates-table rates-bg-row1").table

rows = table.tbody.find_all("tr")

for row in rows:
  for rate in row.find_all("td"):
      print(rate.text)
```